# Unable to extract clicked point value via vba of excel pivotchart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Set clickedPoint=Sheets("SheetName").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(Arg2).Points(Arg1)

This code shows parameter not found.

I'm trying to extract the value of point clicked on a pivot chart embedded on a worksheet. I'm trying to then jump to it's linked pivot table, extract that value's source data, and copy that to a new sheet. I tried jon peltier's chart events for embedded sheets. One section is the above code, which says 'parameter not found'. I can't seem to be able to do the next bit of drilling down to the pivot table data. Hoping for a resolution

Comment: Just guessing, but shouldn't it be `SeriesCollection(Arg1).Points(Arg2)`?